# HttpFileCollectionBase does not allow me to access any of the other MIME multipart header fields

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mime, httpfilecollection

I am constructing a MIME multipart stream that is a collection of various files/data the user has chosen for upload. I then PUT this stream to a URL using asp.net MVC 3 (though the MVC bit should be irrelevant to the question - similar applies to all ASP.NET), where it comes in on the server as a HttpFileCollectionBase object (which is itself basically a collection of HttpPostedFileBase objects).

This all works fine.

However, the HttpPostedFileBase only allows access to the MIME 'media type' and 'filename'
fields. I have other data which I am putting in the

Content-Description:

and

Content-Disposition:

headers in the MIME multipart - but there seems to be no way to access these at the server end. Obviously I realise that media type and filename are the most common fields used and hence I have no problems with having to jump through some hoops to get some of the more esoteric MIME fields. However, I can't see any way to access them at all. Do I need to hook in my own MIME multipart decoding engine into the ASP.NET/MVC framework? If so, where are the hooks, and are there libraries out there that do this without me having to write a MIME decoder.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the raw request body data using the [Request.InputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream.aspx) property. And to access the request HTTP headers you could use the [Request.Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.headers.aspx) property.

Comment: But I'd have to write a custom MIME multipart decoder? I was hoping to avoid that pain. Also, from what I can tell the ASP.NET stuff handles splitting large requests into file objects etc rather than storing the whole request (mine are many megabytes) in memory. I was hoping to use all of that without me doing anything!

Comment: @AndrewPatterson, yes you will have to write a custom MIME parser. I am afraid that what you have hoped is not possible. The ASP.NET already wrote a multipart/form-data parser and provided it to you under the form of the `HttpFileCollectionBase` class. If it doesn't suit your needs I am afraid that you have no other choice but to roll your own.

Comment: This seems like such a waste - it is a pity Microsoft couldn't put a field similar to Request.Headers on each of the HttpPostedFile objects that are created from the MIME multipart decode. I guess I will look into other MIME decoding libraries to see if I can avoid implementing this myself.